# Validación de extensión de archivo en Javascript

Tags: javascript

la duda era si es que se podía validar una extensión de un archivo enviando la extensión por parámetro a la función:

```
function fileValidation(ext){
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
    var filePath = fileInput.value;
    var extension = ext; // la variable ext tiene un valor '.jpeg/.jpg'
    var allowedExtensions = /(extension)$/i; // se que si funciona si se declara -> /(.jpeg/.jpg)$/i;
    if(!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)){
        alert('Porfavor suba archivos con una terminacion '+extension+'.');
        fileInput.value = '';
        return false;
    }
}
```

La declaración se hace de esta manera para que el script sea mas dinámico y reutilizable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que puedas usar la función con diferentes archivos, necesitas enviar dos parámetros:

1. Selector CSS para obtener el campo. '#id-del-campo', '.clase-del-campo' o por etiqueta, si solo hay uno: 'file'
2. Un arreglo con las extensiones permitidas

```js
// Crear arreglos con extensiones permitidas
let allowedImages = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'];
let allowedDocs = ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf'];

// Obtener elemento por ID y que solo admita imágenes
document.querySelector('#file-image').addEventListener('change', () => {
    fileValidation('#file-image', allowedImages);
});

// Obtener elemento por clase y que solo admita documentos
document.querySelector('.file-doc').addEventListener('change', () => {
    fileValidation('.file-doc', allowedDocs);
});

function fileValidation(selector, extensions){
    let filePath = document.querySelector(selector).value || '';
    // Seperar nombre de archivo por . y obtener último elemento (extensión)
    let extension = filePath.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

    // Verificar que la extensión es permitida
    if(!extensions.includes(extension)) {
        alert('Porfavor suba archivos con una extensión vlálida: ' + extensions.join(', '));
        // No puedes manipular el valor del input, solo devolver falso
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<p>Por ID (Solo imágenes): <input type="file" id="file-image"></p>
<p>Por Clase (Solo documentos): <input type="file" class="file-doc"></p>
```

**Importante:** Ten en cuenta que esta función solo considera campos tipo `file` sin el atributo `multiple`.